# Updating getter value Vuex store when state changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to figure out how to properly update a getter value when some other variable from VueX changes/updates.
Currently I'm using this way in a component to update:

```
watch: {
   dates () {
     this.$set(this.linedata[0].chartOptions.xAxis,"categories",this.dates)
   }
}
```

So my getter `linedata` should be updated with `dates` value whenever dates changes. `dates` is state variable from VueX store.
The thing is with this method the value won't be properly updated when I changed route/go to different components. So I think it's better to do this kind of thing using the VueX store.

`dates` is updated with an API call, so I use an action to update it.
So the question is how can I do such an update from the VueX store?

EDIT:

I tried moving this to VueX:

```
async loadData({ commit }) {
      let response = await Api().get("/cpu");
      commit("SET_DATA", {
       this.linedata[0].chartOptions.xAxis,"categories": response.data.dates1,
this.linedata[1].chartOptions.xAxis,"categories": response.data.dates2
      });
    }

 SET_DATA(state, payload) {
      state = Object.assign(state, payload);
    }
```

But the above does not work, as I cannot set nested object in action this way...

Comment: Getters are generally for getting, not setting.  They are like `computed` for Vuex, which return calculated data.  They update automatically when reactive contents change.  So it's probably best to rethink the design so that only state needs to be updated.  Either way, Vuex should be updated only with actions/mutations.

Comment: Hmm okay lets say this `linedata` is then state value. How should I change it? I tired setting that in action I get error when i try to do this: `commit("SET_DATA", {linedata[0].chartoptions.xAxis["categories"]: response.data.dates})`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the bounty!  Very generous.

Comment: No worries, your answer ans explanation in the chat helped me understand much better what happens with data in Vuex store.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getters are generally for getting, not setting. They are like computed for Vuex, which return calculated data. They update automatically when reactive contents change. So it's probably best to rethink the design so that only state needs to be updated. Either way, Vuex should be updated only with actions/mutations

Given your example and the info from all your comments, using `linedata` as state, your action and mutation would look something like this:

```js
actions: {
  async loadData({ commit }) {
    let response = await Api().get("/cpu");
    commit('SET_DATA', response.data.dates);
  }
}
```

```js
mutations: {
  SET_DATA(state, dates) {
    Vue.set(state.linedata[0].chartOptions.xAxis, 'categories', dates[0]);
    Vue.set(state.linedata[1].chartOptions.xAxis, 'categories', dates[1]);
  }
}
```

Which you could call, in the component for example, like:

```js
this.$store.dispatch('loadData');
```

Using `Vue.set` is necessary for change detection in this case and requires the following import:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
```

Theoretically, there should be a better way to design your backend API so that you can just set `state.linedata = payload` in the mutation, but this will work with what you have.

Comment: Would this work with `Object.assign`? For example when in action I would want to set multiple values in state at once? But for some reason `Vue` does not allow me to set nested objects like the one above.

Comment: It's probably because you need `Vue.set`, [which is necessary](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) for change detection when setting array/object items.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Let me give an example what I mean. In actions I'm trying to set several values like state.linedata[0]: `setData({ commit} ) { commit('SET_DATA', {linedata[0].chartoptions.xAxis: response.data.dates1, linedata[1].chartoptions.xAxis:response.data.dates2}); }` and then in mutation:   ` SET_DATA(state, payload) {
      state = Object.assign(state, payload);
    },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209460/discussion-between-dan-and-alex-t).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks. By the way is it good practice to use getters or other state values as a payload? In example above this would mean: `commit('SET_DATA', { id: 0, data: SOMEGETTERHERE/STATEVARIABLE });`

Comment: You're welcome.  I changed my answer a bit too, this is a little cleaner and better.   It's hard to give a comprehensive yes or no on that without analyzing some app, but I can't think of any time I needed to. Passing a getter seems unlikely to be necessary. It would be more likely that you pass an index or id and do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of a Vuex store for an user.

```
export const state = () => ({
  user: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  set(state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },
  unset(state) {
    state.user = {}
  },
  patch(state, user) {
    state.user = Object.assign({}, state.user, user)
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async set({ commit }) {
      // TODO: Get user... 
      commit('set', user)
  },
  unset({ commit }) {
    commit('unset')
  },
  patch({ commit }, user) {
    commit('patch', user)
  }
}

export const getters = {
  get(state) {
    return state.user
  }
}
```

If you want to set the user data, you can call `await this.$store.dispatch('user/set')` in any Vue instance. For patching the data you could call `this.$store.dispatch('user/patch', newUserData)`.

The getter is then reactively updated in any Vue instance where it is mapped. You should use the function `mapGetters` from Vuex in the `computed` properties. Here is an example.

```
...
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    user: 'user/get'
  })
}
...
```

The three dots `...` before the function call is [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which will map all the properties that will the function return in an object to computed properties. Those will then be reactively updated whenever you call `dispatch` on the user store. 
Take a look at Vuex [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for a more in depth explanation.